# Cannot find reference 'cast' in '__init__.py'

Tags: python, pyjnius

I have downloaded pyjnius module using pip and imported in my pycharm project , I was able to import autoclass but not cast(), it gives error "Cannot find reference 'cast' in '**init**.py'"[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Vdt.png), I have manually checked in site-packages and in IDE to find cast() but could not find it.
an example of code importing cast() function from jnius module from documentation website https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/android.html?highlight=cast%20#accessing-the-activity
what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. "I was able to import autoclass but not cast" In your own words, why should you be able to import "cast"? What do you expect that to mean, and why? What do you want to use it for? *Does the documentation say* that there is such a thing as `cast` that you can import? Because I don't see one there. (And why aren't these imports at the top of the file?) Also, please [do not upload images of code or errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also make sure you show an error that you get *from Python*, not your IDE's warning.

Comment: Also, since it wasn't quite clear: if this is not your code in the screenshot, and you are just trying to install dependencies for someone else's project, then you have a *tech support* question that is off topic for Stack Overflow, and which should be addressed by *asking the author* of the code. If you are trying to use the library for your own code, then you should a) *read the [documentation](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io)*; and b) *write less code at a time* and make sure that you can get examples from the documentation working before experimenting.

Comment: The error you posted does not come from the Python interpreter. Your IDE does not find this symbol in that file - that does not mean it isn't there. Open a terminal / console and run `python <path_to_python_file>` to see if Python really throws an error, or if just your IDE has a bug.

Comment: I have the same issue as the user and I think this is a valid question, even it is simply a pycharm bug/misconfiguration.